# Django redirect function keep old url path

Tags: python, django

The problem is when I try to use `django.shortcuts.redirect` in my view function, Django doesn't simply opening new url path from `return redirect('url',)` but add wished url path to current url.

 Example 
Current url is: **/home/page1** 
 On page on button press I call views function which: `return redirect ('**/home/page2**',)`
After this, instead wished url **/home/page2** I recieve **/home/page1/home/page2**
How to get rid of old url part from redirection?

**EDIT:**

Solved by deleting cookies and search history from browser (Chrome), and code work perfectly fine!

Comment: Please show the actual code `return redirect ('/home/page2',)` should not redirect to `/home/page1/home/page2`.

Comment: button in template: <a href="{% url 'home:page2' %}"></a> ; function in home.views: def page2(request): return redirect ('home/page2',)

Answer (score 5):

In the comments you have:

```
return redirect ('home/page2',)
```

This is incorrect. The url must start with a slash, otherwise it will be treated as a relative url.  Change it to:

```
return redirect ('/home/page2')
```

Comment: Either you are not showing the code, or you are not running the code you think you are - `redirect ('/home/page2')` would simply not redirect to `/home/page1/home/page2`.

Comment: It was something wrong with browser (Chrome), after I delete cookies and search history, everything work perfectly fine! Thank you for try to help