# Django Redirecting from views.py to html page

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am using Django 1.11. I have developed some html pages & have views.py
I have page called forgotpassword.html where-in I take EmailId of user. 
I find the respective security question & want to display it to user to enter the answerfor it. I have another page called getpassword.html for this.
Here is the code:
view.py

```
def forgotpassword(request):
   usercontemail = request.POST['useremail']
   #Get the securityquestion from Database  
   return redirect(request,'home/getpassword.html',{'squestion': squestion}) 


def getpassword(request): 
   #Display security question, get the answer from user & proceeed
```

When user enters his email & hits submit I am able to see the input area for user to enter his security answer, which is coming from getpassword.html. But the url remains forgotpassword.html

So when the user enters his Security Answer, I am getting error of useremail cannot be blank. This is because of the url problem.

Can you please suggest workaround?

Comment: Do you submit via JS? Can you show us the template(s)?

Comment: I don't submit via JS. The templates forgotpassword.html & getpassword.html are quite basic.

Comment: Maybe the fact that your redirect URL doesn't start with "/" [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778124/django-redirect-function-keep-old-url-path) has something to do with the error?

Comment: If you have a view that handles the `getpassword.html` page, you can do `return redirect(reverse("home:forgotpassword"))` assuming your app namespace is `home` and the viewname is `forgotpassword`. You also need to import `reverse`

Comment: Yeah, I tired using reverse importing from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, but no success. I am unable to understand even after using return redirect(another page) why the url is not getting changed & I have landed on another page from current page.

Comment: `redirect(request,'home/getpassword.html',{'squestion': squestion})` is a complete hogwash.  `redirect()` expects either a view name, an url or an object having a `get_absolute_url()` method. Here you're passing the same arguments as if you were calling `render()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I was updating a record and my render redirect was rendering the right page but my URL wasn't changing.  What I wasn't aware of was that not only can you render redirect a specific page as you are doing but you can also render redirect a url which is specified in your url.py file.  I found that by specifying a url.py declared url, it kind of sends the request through the normal loop of going to the url file then to the specified view file, passing any declared parameters along the way.

So in your code where you have

```
return redirect(request, 'home/getpassword.html', {'squestion': squestion })
```

you could try

```
#return redirect('app url.py:specified url of view', {*args}
return redirect('home:getpassword', {'squestion': squestion})
```

Just make sure your url.py file specifies the parameters you want to pass.

Check out this article on stackoverflow:
[Django return redirect() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters)

and also the django docs reading the section on render redirect()
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/

Hope it helps.

Comment: "Just make sure your url.py file specifies the parameters you want to pass"
How do we set parameters in urls.py?

Comment: Check out the stackoverflow document I mentioned above.  It has an example in the solution of url(r'^link/(?P<backend>\w+?)/$', my_function). Also check out the Django documents at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/ They explain it far better than I can! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do the redirection not render the template.

```
def forgotpassword(request):
  usercontemail = request.POST['useremail']
  #Get the securityquestion from Database 
  ## you can save the scurtiy question in session or you cn add the 
  ## question id in the url 
  return HttpResponseRedirect("url of the security question page")
```

on the redirection of that, you gave check the method

```
 def getpassword(request):
    if request.METHOD == "GET":
       ## get question from session or from url 
       return redirect(request,'home/getpassword.html',{'squestion':squestion})
    else if request.METHOD == "POST":
          ##submit answer
         #Display security question, get the answer from user & proceeed
```

another method just define the action in your form to URL of get password